# Making thematic map for each column in table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

I have a table with header like
LocationId, Jan, Feb, Mar,.....Dec

I would like to make a graduated symbol map for all the locationIDs for each month, and make an output as a jpg/pdf file. What is the easiest way to do this in ArcGIS?

I can work on it one by one, but what if I get 20 columns to work with? Do I need to do it using ArcObjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can automate this using ArcObjects.

- Use this link to render/set class breaks for your fc field (setup a loop to loop through each of your fields you want to create a map for).

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000vv000000

- Use this export snippet to export out each map (call export class within your field loop).

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Export_active_view/000100000026000000/

Comment: Thanks. I thought there would be some ways integrated in the desktop product.